# EgisTec 0570 Fingerprint Sensor - fprintd-enroll not working

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, hardware, fingerprint

I have an Acer Swift 3 (SF314-57) running arch, which has an 0570 LighTuning Technology Inc. EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor. Support for this device was just made available in the latest libfprint release (v1.92.1), so naturally I have been trying to get it working.

I installed the fprintd package from the official arch repo, however, when I try to enroll a fingerprint, it just 'gets stuck' saying `Enrolling right-index-finger finger` with a blinking cursor, and no amount of trying to scan my fingerprint will get it to give any sort of indication that something is happening.

The device is seen by my system and fprintd.service is running:

```
[sudo] password for mipy: 
● fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-08-08 16:04:25 AEST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:fprintd(1)
   Main PID: 7381 (fprintd)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 18803)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 57ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/fprintd.service
             └─7381 /usr/lib/fprintd

Aug 08 16:04:24 ruby-swift314-57 systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Aug 08 16:04:25 ruby-swift314-57 systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
```

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5c5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1c7a:0570 LighTuning Technology Inc. EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The only errors I get from `journalctl -f -u fprintd.service` are:

```
fprintd[6957]: Failed to clear storage before first enrollment: Device has no storage.
```

(I should add, my disk has ~50GB of storage available, so the problem isnt with my disk's storage - I assume the reader's?)

When I build libfprint from source, using `meson compile` and then `meson test`, and try to enroll using the examples, it shows:

```
This program will enroll the selected finger, unconditionally overwriting any print for the same finger that was enrolled previously. If you want to continue, press enter, otherwise hit Ctrl+C

Choose the finger to enroll:
  [0] left thumb
  [1] left index
  [2] left middle
  [3] left ring
  [4] left little
  [5] right thumb
  [6] right index
  [7] right middle
  [8] right ring
  [9] right little
> 6
(process:5575): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:21:02.406: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0003
(process:5575): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:21:02.406: No driver found for USB device 04F2:B5C5
(process:5575): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:21:02.407: No driver found for USB device 8087:0026
(process:5575): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:21:02.407: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0002
(process:5575): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:21:02.407: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0003
(process:5575): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:21:02.407: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0002
Selected device 0 (Egis Technology Inc. (aka. LighTuning) 0570) claimed by egis0570 driver
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.490: Image device open completed
(process:6437): libfprint-device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.490: Device reported open completion
(process:6437): libfprint-device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.491: Completing action FPI_DEVICE_ACTION_OPEN in idle!
Opened device. It's now time to enroll your finger.

You will need to successfully scan your right index finger 5 times to complete the process.

Scan your finger now.
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: Activating image device
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: Image device internal state change from FPI_IMAGE_DEVICE_STATE_INACTIVE to FPI_IMAGE_DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVATING
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 0
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 1
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: Image device activation completed
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: Image device internal state change from FPI_IMAGE_DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVATING to FPI_IMAGE_DEVICE_STATE_IDLE
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: Image device internal state change from FPI_IMAGE_DEVICE_STATE_IDLE to FPI_IMAGE_DEVICE_STATE_AWAIT_FINGER_ON
(process:6437): libfprint-device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: Device reported finger status change: FP_FINGER_STATUS_NEEDED
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.492: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.493: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.493: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.493: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.493: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.493: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.493: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.494: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.495: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.496: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.497: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 4
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.564: Image device reported finger status: off
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.564: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 5
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.564: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 1
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.564: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.564: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.564: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.565: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.565: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.565: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.565: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 2
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.565: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 3
(process:6437): libfprint-SSM-DEBUG: 15:33:00.565: [egis0570] SM_STATES_NUM entering state 4
(process:6437): libfprint-egis0570-DEBUG: 15:33:00.632: Finger status (picture number, mean) : 0 , 0
(process:6437): libfprint-egis0570-DEBUG: 15:33:00.632: Finger status (picture number, mean) : 1 , 0
(process:6437): libfprint-egis0570-DEBUG: 15:33:00.632: Finger status (picture number, mean) : 2 , 0
(process:6437): libfprint-egis0570-DEBUG: 15:33:00.632: Finger status (picture number, mean) : 3 , 0
(process:6437): libfprint-egis0570-DEBUG: 15:33:00.632: Finger status (picture number, mean) : 4 , 0
(process:6437): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:33:00.632: Image device reported finger status: off
```

And just keeps looping through the "Finger status" and "SM_STATES_NUM" bit until I kill it.

When I then try using manage-prints from the examples, I get:

```
This program will report the prints saved in device
(process:7187): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:56:24.549: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0003
(process:7187): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:56:24.549: No driver found for USB device 04F2:B5C5
(process:7187): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:56:24.549: No driver found for USB device 8087:0026
(process:7187): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:56:24.549: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0002
(process:7187): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:56:24.549: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0003
(process:7187): libfprint-context-DEBUG: 15:56:24.549: No driver found for USB device 1D6B:0002
Selected device 0 (Egis Technology Inc. (aka. LighTuning) 0570) claimed by egis0570 driver
(process:7187): libfprint-image_device-DEBUG: 15:56:24.690: Image device open completed
(process:7187): libfprint-device-DEBUG: 15:56:24.691: Device reported open completion
(process:7187): libfprint-device-DEBUG: 15:56:24.691: Completing action FPI_DEVICE_ACTION_OPEN in idle!

(process:7187): libfprint-WARNING **: 15:56:24.691: Device Egis Technology Inc. (aka. LighTuning) 0570 doesn't support storage

(process:7187): libfprint-device-WARNING **: 15:56:24.691: User destroyed open device! Not cleaning up properly!
libusb: warning [libusb_exit] application left some devices open
```

When I try and run `fwupdmgr update`, I just get:

```
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • System Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI dbx
 • WDC PC SN520 SDAPNUW-512G-1014
No updatable devices
```

Does anybody know what is going on? I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks :)

Comment: Further discussion and solution are [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/418)